# Is it possible to run ASP.NET 5 site directly on Kestrel in Azure WebApps?

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service, dnx, kestrel-http-server

I have checked that in the web response the server is IIS when I deploy ASP.NET5 to azure web app, so I guess the IIS platform handler is used to redirect it to Kestrel. So I am wondering if it is possible to run directly on Kestrel, and what benefits/drawbacks will that have (probably regardless if it's in Azure or not). I suppose it will be a bit faster since IIS will be excluded from the pipline, but it should not be too much overhead I suppose...

Comment: I think need start dnx.exe in web role. [Something like this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/331425/Running-an-EXE-in-a-WebRole-on-Windows-Azure)

Comment: I use Azure Web App, I guess it's something else, not the web role

Answer (score 11, accepted):

On Azure Web App, you cannot bypass IIS.

But in the general case, you can definitely run Kestrel directly. It is after all just `dnx web` and it's exactly what the XPlat version (Linux, OSX) will end-up using (almost).

### What you lose from not using IIS

- Security (newer component compared to IIS)
- Easy setup of SSL
- Kernel module that handle file/cache and other things (kernel = faster)
- Application monitoring/Keep-Alive (what happens if Kestrel crash)
- Multiple hostnames single-port (80) reuse
- etc.

### What you gain from not using IIS

- Complete control over your process
- Higher overall performance
- Simpler installation/execution

### What you should do if you choose not to use IIS

If you are OK with the "lose" points, I would still go and host your Kestrel behind a reverse proxy or an NGINX server. Kestrel was made to be "production ready" but it's not NGINX or IIS.

It will not keep itself alive as far as I know.

If I missed anything, please let me know.

Comment: Do you mean ssl e.g. by security? Or is there something that is insecure about Kestrel? I am not sure how to start it in WebApp either, not sure about what you mean by simpler installation either, since you don't install anything in WebApp

Comment: Not insecure but it relatively new compared to IIS so I'm still a bit shy of hosting it that way ;-) As for SSL, it's also a bit harder to do with Kestrel compared to IIS.

Comment: I suppose it's quite hard to setup ssl on kestrel on Web App as well. Since the default setup will use IIS. I guess I'll just not try to improvise and use the default IIS to Kestrel setup that web apps use. Thank you for help :)

Comment: To be fair, IIS 10 will use Kestrel too. It will just start the process and forward requests to it. :) One way or another, you are using Kestrel. :)

Comment: I did not know :) Interesting fact, why would they do that, IIS was working pretty well

Comment: Cross Platform. If you tie yourself to IIS, you can't use Linux or OSX. If you untie yourself from IIS too much, you lose performance benefits. So they have to make compromises.

Comment: @StasBoyarincev `dnx` should be runable from the command prompt. `dnx web` should be runable from the directory where your `project.json` is.

Comment: I mean calling in Azure Web App.

Comment: That's the answer for the general question, but it doesn't apply to Azure Web App. I added another answer to focus on that.

Comment: @DavidEbbo want to edit my answer and include it in it? I am but a mere MVP here. :P

Comment: @MaximeRouiller ok, I added note at the top to clarify. Thanks!

Comment: Is it still actual?

Answer (score 6):

Your question is a bit ambiguous, as it asks at the same time about Azure Web Apps and about the general case. @Maxime answered the general part, so I'll answer the Azure Web App part.

It is *not* possible to bypass IIS in Azure Web Apps. Stack that normally run without IIS are typically handled using `HttpPlatformHandler` (as is the case for ASP.NET 5), or in the case of Node some variant of that (iisnode).

Comment: What you think abourt start dnx process into azure web role ?

Comment: Sorry, my expertize is more on the Azure Web App side, so I couldn't give an answer for Web Role with much authority. :)

Comment: If running Azure API gateway, wouldn't that take care of some of the security considerations? API Gateway -> IIS -> Kestrel seems inefficient.