# Azure web app equivalent of an existing nTier application

Tags: azure

We have an application which is an Asp MVC application which communicates via WCF to a middle tier application. We will be rewriting this and want to target Azure

It's split into 3 tiers, web, business, database, which are all on separate machines, as some of the business processes can take a few seconds. When the web calls the middle tier it must wait for a response before returning to the user, i.e. something like a message queue isn't appropriate here

I'm thinking for the new architecture we have

Client: AngularJS

Web: Probably Asp MVC controllers in a Web App

Middle tier: ?

Database: Azure SQL Database

The middle tier is where it gets confusing, what is this in terms of Web Apps and how does it communicate with the web? I think we'd prefer a RPC approach rather than REST based if possible. We just want to send serialized classes back and forth

What about scalability? We're presently assuming that the web will need to be stateless

Comment: What kind of bindings do you use in the WCF tier?

Comment: This will be a completely new application, we are free to use anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Azure Web Apps is a platform that builds on top of IIS, you can run an IIS-hosted WCF-service on Web Apps just fine.

As for scalability, Azure App Service allows you to scale horizontally manually or automatically.

If the Web and Middle tier share scaling requirements, you can place both on the same App Service Plan. Then they share the instances and scale simultaneously. If however their scaling requirements are quite different, I recommend you put them in their own App Service Plans. Then one's scaling doesn't affect the other.

Comment: They build on IIS, is this a requirement? The wcf service won't need anything from IIS, I'm thinking of performance here.

Comment: API Apps host in HTTP.SYS - Just make sure you use `basicHttpBinding` for WCF since you can't do arbitrary socket binding in App Service.

Comment: Hmm now i'm having second thoughts about my statement. It could be just WCF in IIS after all and i'm just confused..

Comment: From http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34312569/is-it-possible-to-run-asp-net-5-site-directly-on-kestrel-in-azure-webapps

"On Azure Web App, you cannot bypass IIS."