# Publishing asp.net core to azure... want to use kestrel not IIS in the cloud

Tags: azure, .net-core, kestrel-http-server

When I publish my `asp.net core 2.0` to the azure cloud, I have a misconfiguration and I am given an error originating from IIS instead of Kestrel

> HTTP Error 502.5 - Process Failure
>
> ...
>
> The application process started but failed to listen on the configured port
>
> For more information visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=808681

How can I make Azure cloud use Kestrel and not IIS?

Comment: what service are you using?

Comment: Apparently this is not possible (yet?) https://stackoverflow.com/a/34314236/73804

Comment: on webapps - not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, this is not possible (yet?)

- See: [Is it possible to run ASP.NET 5 site directly on Kestrel in Azure WebApps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34312569/is-it-possible-to-run-asp-net-5-site-directly-on-kestrel-in-azure-webapps)