# Exactly how does .NET Core 2.0 work on Azure WebApp?

Tags: iis, .net-core

So there are plenty of resources the explain how to get your .net core app published to Azure WebApp.  That's not what I'm asking b/c that is straight-forward.  But what I haven't been able to track down in searching is exactly how it works once it's published.  In this SO: [Is it possible to run ASP.NET 5 site directly on Kestrel in Azure WebApps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34312569/is-it-possible-to-run-asp-net-5-site-directly-on-kestrel-in-azure-webapps), the accepted answer indicates "On Azure Web App, you cannot bypass IIS."  If that is true, exactly HOW is a .NET Core 2.0 boilerplate app (in this case created with VS 2017 templates), able to work?

In this //build video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7TERFQ_U9W0, Daniel explains how you can use web.config to setup your .net core app behind IIS.  This makes sense, but the boilerplate .net core app that I created with VS 2017 has none of this configuration.

So what I'm confused about is: if my .net core app has no specific configuration to use IIS, and if in Azure WebApp you "cannot bypass IIS", how then, am I able to easily publish my asp.net core app to my Azure WebApp and have it "just work"?

Is something happening during the publish process that I don't know about? The way I published was by downloading the publish profile from my Azure WebApp, and then importing it into my project in VS and hitting "publish."

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing it, but I looked through both links you sent, and as far as I can tell, those tutorials are focused on HOW to deploy your dot net core app to an azure web app, which is precisely what I said I was not asking about. Rather, I wanted to know the details behind how it worked when my source code had no specific config for putting IIS in front of kestrel (and we know that azure app requires IIS). But I found the answer and posted it for anyone elsr who may have been wondering, or, like me, did not at first think to check the pubtmp output.

Comment: Youou really should reformat your question. You are more interested in the technical details behind the commands, which usually only hides in source code or blog posts, like https://blog.lextudio.com/how-visual-studio-launches-iis-express-to-debug-asp-net-core-apps-d7fd3677e3c3 there are much more tricks unsaid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, well it looks like, indeed, during the publish process something is in fact configuring the IIS part.  I went and looked at the PubTmp\Out folder (which in hindsight, I should have done first I guess) and found a web.config file that I didn't create.  And what do you know, it has:

```
<aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\MyApp.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
```

So this is for the benefit of any other idiots like me out there who didn't think to check the PubTmp\Out folder for a clue.